# Ionic build failed because of Geofencing Plugin

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I installed the community plugin geofencing on my ionic projcet. When I now try to build the project, the build fails. The console output is:

```
The following build commands failed:
        CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/maius/Documents/unverpacktewahrheiten/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-geofence/GeofencePlugin.swift
        CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/maius/Documents/unverpacktewahrheiten/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-geofence/SwiftyJson.swift
        CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(3 failures)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
```

I tried to change those files with the ones from the git repo as it is explained in some other questions, but that didn't solve the problem.

And those are the versions of ionic, etc. :

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.13 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 9 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.10.0
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v12.13.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.13.4
   OS         : macOS Mojave
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.2.1 Build version 11B500
```

I think it could help to change to an earlier version, but couldn't figure out which one.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Following the below steps.

1. uninstall geofence plugin.
2. uninstall platform iOS
3. install geofence plugin
4. replace these 3 file (https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence/tree/master/src/ios 69)
5. install the platform iOS.
6. build succeeds